# Not loading JS and CSS files when loading html in to Uiwebview IOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I had an application in which I am downloading the html file and with js and css files in to application document directory.Then When i am adding the html in to UIwebview the CSS files are not loading.I am doing like this

```
`  NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;

    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];



    NSArray *ipaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *idocumentsDir = ([ipaths count] > 0) ? [ipaths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dictionary valueForKey:@"htmlfilename"]];
    NSString *idataPath = [idocumentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:str];
    NSLog(@"idataPath:%@",idataPath);

    //Create folder here
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:idataPath])
    {





        NSError *err;
        NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:idataPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];
        html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"../css/style-ios.css" withString:@"./style-ios.css"];
        html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"../.././style-ios.css" withString:@"./style-ios.css"];
        html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"../../../style-ios.css" withString:@"./style-ios.css"];
        html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"../../../lib/js-ios.js" withString:@"./js-ios.js"];


        NSLog(@"%@",html);
       [self.formswebview loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:idataPath]];



    }
`
```

But this is not loading css files.Can anybody please guide me on where i am going wrong?